# Delete lines based on time stamp in text file PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Novice at PS here, but I have a log file where each entry is written on a separate line with this date format: 2013-04-29 08:55:09,261

I am trying to use PowerShell to delete all lines older than 30 days. I have been trying to plug get-date -format  "yyyy-MM-dd hh" output with some sort of greater than code, but at this point I’m just guessing. Also been trying forfiles with a batch file but would like to stick with PS if I can.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would help greatly if you showed your actual code. Even if it doesn't work, it gives people a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a file with the contents:

```
2013-04-29 08:55:09,261 line1
2013-01-29 08:55:09,261 line2
2013-03-31 08:55:09,261 line3
```

For me your dates are in the international standard date notation so you can just use :

```
$a = [datetime]"2013-04-29 08:55:09"
```

Then `$a` will be a date, so nothing to do with the culture.

You can just write the following to filter all lines from a date (here "2013-03-31")

```
get-content "C:\temp\date.txt" | where { [datetime]($_.split(','))[0] -ge "2013-03-31"}
```

I just split the line on the coma, take the first part and convert it to a date before compararing it.

For your 30 days `(get-date).date` give the date without hours and `(get-date).date.adddays(-30)` give the date 30 days before today.

```
get-content C:\temp\date.txt | where { [datetime]($_.split(','))[0] -ge (get-date).date.adddays(-30)}
```

You can pipe the result in a new file `| set-content "C:\temp\newdate.txt"`

Comment: Most of the code in this thread worked well and gave the desired results. Only main difference was the run time.  I went with this one since it ran a bit quicker, but anyone coming across this thread should have some options and all should work well.  I will try to comment on the other contributions as well to give my results. Thanks all, very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
gc .\logfile.txt | %{if ([datetime][regex]::match($_, '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}').Value -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)) {$_}} > purgedlogfile.txt
```

Breakdown and explanation of the components:

- `.\logfile.txt` is the path to the log file
- `^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}` is a regular expression that matches your log file's timestamp format at the beginning of each line
- `[regex]::match($_, '^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}').Value` returns the timestamp matched by the regular expression
- Preceding it with the `[datetime]` typecast operator converts it to a DateTime object (in order to compare it to another DateTime)
- `(Get-Date)` returns a DateTime object representing the current date and time, and `.AddDays(-30)` subtracts 30 days from it, to return a DateTime object representing 30 days ago
- For each line in the logfile, the `if` block prints the line if the DateTime representing that line's timestamp is greater than the DateTime representing 30 days ago (i.e., the timestamp is more recent than 30 days), otherwise it ignores the line

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a file with the contents:

```
2013-04-29 08:55:09,261 line1
2013-01-29 08:55:09,261 line2
2013-03-31 08:55:09,261 line3
```

You could get your desired output with:

```
$culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
$format = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff'

Get-Content .\test.txt | ? { [datetime]::ParseExact(([string]$_).Substring(0,23), $format, $culture) -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) }
```

Comment: This one got removing the older than 30 days lines right, but for some reason it missing anything after 13:00 hours until the next day. Example 2013-04-29 13:07:42,027 to 2013-04-29 23:57:10,425 would be missing. Probably something to do with 24hr clock format?? Very beginner at PS, so not sure, but I wanted to share my results.

Comment: @olirm - yep, my mistake, my format was specifying 12 hour format instead of 24 - fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Adi Inbar's answer is good, but if you'd prefer to avoid regular expressions, here's another way:

```
Get-Content e:\pathto\logfile.txt | Where-Object { ( (Get-Date) - (Get-Date $_.Substring(0,10)) ).Days -le 30} | Add-Content e:\pathto\NewLog.txt
```