# Batch to delete older lines

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a txt file which contains a series of data like this

```
   Date      Time          Id    Set
2020/05/04 15:22:28      10005   4512
2020/05/04 15:23:47      10005   4528
2020/05/04 15:23:48      10005   4543
2020/05/04 15:23:58      10005   4555
2020/05/04 15:24:00      10005   4533
2020/05/04 15:24:03      10005   4512
2020/05/04 15:24:05      10005   4590
```

I need to delete the oldest lines based on the writing time, how can I get this final result in the txt file?

```
2020/05/04 15:24:05      10005   4590
```

---

Sorry for my ability, I'm trying

```
    powershell.exe -Command get-content "D:\filelog.txt" | where { [datetime]($_.split(','))[0] -ge (get-date).date.adddays(-30)} 
set-content "D:\Newfilelog.txt"
```

Obviously I'm wrong, since it doesn't work

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: I can't find anything I can do to get the result, any suggestions are well accepted

Comment: Do you ***really*** use the MS-DOS operating system, or you have Windows?

Comment: i am using windows

Comment: Try using vbscript.  You can run it using the cscript command.  Alternatively do it in powershell.

Comment: I was thinking about powershell but I don't really know how to set the commands

Comment: Try using [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell?tab=Newest). Something like [this: Delete lines based on time stamp in text file PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286413/delete-lines-based-on-time-stamp-in-text-file-powershell)?

Comment: **You need to better explain what exactly you're needing to do, because based upon what you've posted this seems like a very trivial task for a batch file**. The file you have posted clearly indicates that your date and time strings are already written in order oldest to newest, so all you really need is the last line with data. If your written lines were not in oldest to newest data and time order, because they're clearly in universally sortable order format, you could simply sort the file, either in standard sort order, selecting the last data line, or in reverse order, selecting the first.

Answer (score 1):

'Tis an ancient question, but since, given the data, what is required is the first line (header) and last,

```
(
 set "line="
 for /F "delims=" %%L in (input.txt) do (
 if not defined line echo %%L
 set "line=%%L"
 )
 echo %line%
)>"output.txt"
```

The enclosing parentheses allow the `echo` output to be redirected to the file.

Otherwise, force `line` to be undefined, then `echo` the first line as `line` is then undefined, and thenassign the data read to `line`

When the reading is finished, the last line is in `line`, so `echo` it.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data in ascending order and read the last line:

```cmd
rem /* Sort the data in ascending (alphabetic) order, excluding the first line;
rem    then loop through the sorted lines: */
for /F "delims=" %%L in ('more +1 "input.txt" ^| sort') do (
    rem /* Store the current (non-empty) line; this value overwritten in each iteration,
    rem    so eventually the last line is stored in the variable: */
    set "LAST=%%L"
)
rem // Read the first line (header) of the data:
< "input.txt" (set "FIRST=" & set /P FIRST="")
rem // Return the gathered information (first and last lines):
if defined LAST (
    > "output.txt" (
        echo %FIRST%
        echo %LAST%
    )
)
```